# Invalid argument: Cannot parse tensor from proto: dtype: DT_FLOAT

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, protobuf-net

I'm currently attempting to run a Convolutional Neural Network on a data-set of images I have. Each image is a numpy array with dimensions 300, 300, 1. I'm using the most up to date versions of Tensorflow and Keras. My X_Train has dimensions 195850, 300, 300, 1. My X_Test has dimensions 48850, 300, 300, 1. My Y_Train is a vector of 195850 elements, which was turned into a one hot vector using the to_categorical function.

Here is my code :

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, MaxPooling2D, Convolution2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import applications, backend as K
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
import pickle
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

K.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')
nb_train_samples = 195850
nb_validation_samples = 48850

X_train = pickle.load(open(r'C:\Users\...\Documents\GitHub\ASL_Data\X_Train.pkl', 'rb'))
#X_train = np.moveaxis(np.array(X_train), 0, -1)

Y_train = pickle.load(open(r'C:\Users\...\Documents\GitHub\ASL_Data\Y_Train.pkl', 'rb'))
#Y_train = np.moveaxis(np.array(Y_train), 0, -1)

X_test = pickle.load(open(r'C:\Users\...\Documents\GitHub\ASL_Data\X_Test.pkl', 'rb'))
#X_test = np.moveaxis(np.array(X_test), 0, -1)

Y_test = pickle.load(open(r'C:\Users\\Documents\GitHub\ASL_Data\Y_Test.pkl', 'rb'))
#Y_test = np.moveaxis(np.array(Y_test), 0, -1)

print('X_train shape: ', np.array(X_train).shape)
print('Y_train shape: ', np.array(Y_train).shape)

epochs = 50
batch_size = 50
nb_batches = nb_train_samples // batch_size

input_shape = (300, 300)

print ('before model')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), data_format="channels_last", input_shape=(300, 300, 1,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=(300, 300, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), input_shape=(300, 300, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(696))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

print ('before model compile')

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            optimizer='rmsprop',
            metrics=['accuracy'])

print ('after model')

for e in range(0, epochs):
    for i in range(0, nb_batches):

        start= i * batch_size
        end = start + batch_size
        channel = np.ones(1)
        x_train = np.array(X_train[start:end][:][:])
        x_train = x_train.reshape(batch_size, 300, 300, 1)

        x_test = np.array(X_test[start:end][:][:])
        x_test = x_test.reshape(batch_size, 300, 300, 1)

        y_train = np.array(Y_train[start:end][:])
        y_test = np.array(Y_test[start:end][:])
        print('y_train shape: ', np.array(y_train).shape)

        y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=696)
        y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=696)
        print('y_train shape: ', np.array(y_train).shape)



        model.train_on_batch(x_train, y_train)
        model.test_on_batch(x_test, y_test)
```

As you can see, I am using the train_on_batch function, although I don't think that should be the origin of my errors, which are :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\Documents\GitHub\ASL_Data\train2.py", line 86, in <module>
    model.train_on_batch(x_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 955, in train_on_batch
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1762, in train_on_batch
    outputs = self.train_function(ins)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2270, in __call__
    session = get_session()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 167, in get_session
    _initialize_variables()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 341, in _initialize_variables
    sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(uninitialized_variables))
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1124, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot parse tensor from proto: dtype: DT_FLOAT
tensor_shape {
  dim {
    size: 11063808
  }
  dim {
    size: 256
  }
}
float_val: 0

         [[Node: training/RMSprop/Const_6 = Const[dtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor<type: float shape: [11063808,256] values: [0 0 0]...>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'training/RMSprop/Const_6', defined at:
  File "C:\Users\...\Documents\GitHub\ASL_Data\train2.py", line 86, in <module>
    model.train_on_batch(x_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 955, in train_on_batch
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1761, in train_on_batch
    self._make_train_function()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 960, in _make_train_function
    loss=self.total_loss)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers.py", line 226, in get_updates
    accumulators = [K.zeros(K.int_shape(p), dtype=K.dtype(p)) for p in params]
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers.py", line 226, in <listcomp>
    accumulators = [K.zeros(K.int_shape(p), dtype=K.dtype(p)) for p in params]
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 625, in zeros
    return variable(tf.constant_initializer(0., dtype=tf_dtype)(shape),
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\init_ops.py", line 203, in __call__
    verify_shape=verify_shape)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 106, in constant
    attrs={"value": tensor_value, "dtype": dtype_value}, name=name).outputs[0]
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2630, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1204, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot parse tensor from proto: dtype: DT_FLOAT
tensor_shape {
  dim {
    size: 11063808
  }
  dim {
    size: 256
  }
}
float_val: 0

         [[Node: training/RMSprop/Const_6 = Const[dtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor<type: float shape: [11063808,256] values: [0 0 0]...>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

I'm really stuck here so any help is greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: If you replace `Flatten()` by `GlobalAveragePooling2D()`, will the error disappear?

Comment: I think it may be memory error when TF tries to allocate memory for such a large `Dense` layer.

Comment: Thanks, using GlobalAveragePooling2D() fixed it. Thanks a lot for your help.